# How will the unit spheres volume change after mapping

Tags: linear-algebra, map-projections

Let $R^3$ be a vector space. Linear map $F$ will map base of $R^3$:

$u_1=(1,2,-1)^T$, $u_2=(1,-3,3)^T$, $u_3=(-1,-2,2)^T$

on vectors

$v_1=(-1,-3,5)^T$, $v_2=(2,5,-4)^T$, $v_3=(-2,-6,7)^T$.

How will the unit spheres volume change after mapping it with F?

Comment: The volume of $S\subseteq\mathbb R^3$ under a linear map $F\colon\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R^3$ changes as $\operatorname{vol}(F(S))=\det(F)\cdot\operatorname{vol}(S)$. Hence, all you need to do is calculate the determinant of $F$.

Comment: so it will be det(F)-times changed? thank you!